# Find the biggest possible order of element in the group $Z_2 \times Z_{36} \times Z_{10}$.Give an element in the group that has the order we found

Tags: group-theory

Find the biggest possible order of element in the group $Z_2 \times Z_{36} \times Z_{10}$. Give  an element  in the group that has the order we found.

> How I can find the biggest order?

I saw an example that we found all the alements but here I think it is difficult because we have many elements in this group.

Comment: **Hint:** An element in the product group is a triple of elements from each of the factors. The order of the element is the _least common multiple_ of the orders of its components.

Answer (score 0):

*Working on the hint by @HenningMakholm . . .*

Each element of $\Bbb Z_2\times\Bbb Z_{36}\times\Bbb Z_{10}$ is a triplet $([a]_2, [b]_{36}, [c]_{10})$ and its order is $\operatorname{lcm}(A, B, C)$, where $A$ is the order of $[a]_2$ in $\Bbb Z_2$, $B$ is the order of $[b]_{36}$ in $\Bbb Z_{36}$, and $C$ is the order of $[c]_{10}$ in $\Bbb Z_{10}$.